# bx-slider changes direction after a while

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using bx-slider, `infiniteLoop=true`, but there's an issue when after a while of clicking to the next slide, it changes direction to the left, and then continue to the right,and then continue with normal flow, and after a while it happens again, any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: May you post an issue and your code as a snippet?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question isn't really answerable without sample code; please include a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.